# Slave can't pull I2C low

Tags: stm32, i2c

I'm trying to use 3 TCA9539PWR and a TCA6408A on an I2C bus.

Here's the schematic diagram:

[image]

However, when I try to send the TCA9539PWR's addresses , none of them responds (no ACK) and when I try to send the address of TCA6408A (0x40,) the wave shows that it can't pull down the bus fully.

[image]

I use 10k pull-up resistors, and I think it's the resistor is strong enough;I can't change the res on the pcb easily, so it's hard for me to test that.

That's a part of the code I use to control the SDA and SCL:

```
void SDA_OUT(void) //init SDA to send Data
{
   GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
   GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
   GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
   GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = I2C_SDA_Pin;
   HAL_GPIO_Init(I2C_PORT, &GPIO_InitStruct );
}

//...

void SDA_IN(void)    //release the SDA wire
{
   GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
   GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
   GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
   GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = I2C_SDA_Pin;
   HAL_GPIO_Init(I2C_PORT, &GPIO_InitStruct );
}

//The SCL wire was initialized by STM32CUBEMX;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = I2C_SDA_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

Comment: Would you show the code where the SDA and SCL pins are initialized?

Comment: @Justme Sure,I've edited my question.Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the GPIO mode be at an open-drain mode? You are using push-pull mode GPIO. I think that might be the issue.

Comment: I don't understand why bitbanging the I2C in software as the STM32 contains a I2C peripheral so you don't have to bitbang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I2C pins must not be set to output high. You are using push-pull outputs. STM32 can configure them as open-drain outputs. In that case it is not even necessary to change it to input for reading. In reality you would not bit-bang the protocol yourself as the STM32 contains an i2C peripheral.

Comment: The other way to bit-bang I2C without using open-collector mode is to pre-set the output register bit to zero and switch to mode register for the output value: input for high (actually high-Z) or output for drive low.

Answer (score 1):

SDA line should be configured as open drain, not as push-pull.
With push-pull the slave is pulling low, while your master is pulling high.